# Express an integer as the sum of some other fixed integers

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have a fixed list of weights:

```
int[] weights = new int[] { 10, 15, 20 };
```

and a target:

```
int target = 28;
```

I am looking for an algorithm to express `target` as the sum of elements from `weights` (with repeats allowed) such that `target` is either matched or *exceeded*, the closest possible match to `target` is achieved, and within that, the **number** of weights used is minimised.

So with the above input I would like either `10 20` or `15 15` to be returned, since `30` is as close as we can get, and of the options for making `30`, these two are better than `10 10 10`.

With a `target` of `39`, the output should be `20 20` rather than, say, `15 15 10` or `10 10 10 10`.

With a `target` of `14`, the output should be `15`.

Is there a good approach here other than regular foreach loops? I was thinking of retreiving the largest value available in the array and check if the target is negative, if not then let's go for the next value.

This is not homework :)

Comment: I don't understand the _"If my weight would have been 39 the result would have been 20 and 20. "_ There's only one 20 in the array.

Comment: So, you can select the same value multiple times from the array, and you want the sum of the selected values to be greater or equal to the target value. Presumably, you want the lowest possible sum, and *also* to minimize the number of selected values? E.g. 10, 10, 10 is a worse choice when target=28?

Comment: I don't understand `"In the example above the selection should be 20 and 10"`. Why 10?

Comment: This means that the amount adds up, I want to ENUMERATE this so that the summed values from the array gets bigger than the weight. I'll clarify my question

Comment: Essentially, from the array of values, he wants to find the closes number he can to the weight. So if his weight is 30, the closest number he can make from the array is with 20 and 10

Comment: Also, if 20,20 is valid for 38, why is 15,15 not valid for 28?

Comment: 15,15 would be equally valid for 28 as 20,10 is

Comment: Your edit hasn't made things much clearer - enumeration usually refers to using each member value once. Take a step back, try to carefully describe what the rules are, why one selection is preferred over another, when/how the same value can be reused, etc.

Comment: for `28` wouldn't `10` and `20` be equally as good as two `15`s?

Comment: Tim, start eating. Im working on some basics in a logistic system

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The question is, why is 10+10+10 not valid for 28?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I covered that combination in my first query - are we seeking to minimize the number of selections made, in addition to the other constraints?

Comment: Everyone: I've rewritten to incorporate everything discussed here in the comments. @Trikks please check I haven't changed the problem

Comment: Almost a bit fancy but it will do. Thanks!

Comment: @Trikks What do you except for `weight = 16`? `15` or `20`? I asked since the last edit changed the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution thanks to everyone here making it a bit more clear what I actually needed. It's not the prettiest code I've written but this is MVP development anyway!

```
private static List<int> WeightsJuggle(List<int> packages, IOrderedEnumerable<int> weights, int weight)
{
    if (weight == 0)
        return packages;

    foreach (int i in weights.Where(i => i >= weight))
    {
        packages.Add(i);
        return packages;
    }

    packages.Add(weights.Max());
    return WeightsJuggle(packages, weights, weight - weights.Max());
}
```

I call it like this

```
IOrderedEnumerable<int> weights = new int[] { 10, 15, 20 }.OrderBy(x => x);
int weight = 65;
List<int> packages = new List<int>();
```

**Test with weight 65**

[image]

**Test with weight 123**

[image]

Comment: Does not work correct. Try it with `weight = 30`. The result will be `20, 15`, but it should be either `20, 10` or `15, 15`.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The only difference is that you're looking for the *nearest* match, instead of the *nearest lower* match. Also fortunately none of the weights have a different value. The difficulty lies in that you cannot simply use one of the `weights` that comes closest and recurse using the remaining value (a combination of smaller values would sometimes make a better match).

In your example the `weights` all have 5 "units" in between, if this is always the case, the problem will become alot easier to solve.